# Can I know the streaming server or the method use for streaming live video from an website

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I see a website that streaming live videos, I want to know the method used for streaming in this given website.
there is any solution to know which server or provider for streaming there videos
the link of streaming is like this:
a-go11.streamtec.xyz/hls22/stream-2991.ts?Key=HxDJ19GJwT1yjfSL347p_A&Expires=1647114560

Answer (score 1):

You've identified the method in your question's tags... HLS.

The relevant clues:

- It's a segmented stream, so if it's following common standards, that's HLS or DASH.
- It's using MPEG-TS segments, so that's HLS.
- It says *HLS* in the URL.  :-)
- Probably in another request, you'll see the HLS playlist, typically named `.m3u8`.